# Configuring Datasource in Spring 3.0

Tags: spring, glassfish

Hello guys I have configured a connection pool and JNDI resource in glassfish 2.1. I can get the Datasource via lookup method in my projects and everything works good. However I decided to try Spring framework and to use my existing connection pool.

In the Spring context file I have the following:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/name" />
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dao" class="com.mycompany.mavenproject3.Dao">
    <property name="simpleJdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

When I deploy the project I get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'dataSource' or 'jdbcTemplate' is     required]

Is there anything else I have to configure in that file or in any other file in order  to get the Datasource?

Comment: Please show us the full stack trace and error message, not just one line of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, com.mycompany.mavenproject3.Dao extends [JdbcDaoSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/JdbcDaoSupport.html), but you're setting a property named simpleJdbcTemplate on it, leading me to believe that you've defined your own property to hold the template since that doesn't exist on Spring's implementation. It's therefore complaining at you because you're required to set either the [dataSource property](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/JdbcDaoSupport.html#setDataSource%28javax.sql.DataSource%29) or the [jdbcTemplate property](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/support/JdbcDaoSupport.html#setJdbcTemplate%28org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate%29) of the JdbcDaoSupport object before using it, exactly like it's telling you. Change `<property name="simpleJdbcTemplate"...` to `<property name="jdbcTemplate"...`.

If your DAO doesn't extend JdbcDaoSupport, then find what does and remove it or set its properties appropriately.

Comment: Also setting `<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>` on eliminates the need for defining the `jdbcTemplate` bean (assuming c.m.mavenproject3.Dao extends `SimpleJdbcDaoSupport`

Comment: Hello, yes my class extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport. You were right, there is not a property called simpleJdbcTemplate, so when I changed the property name, it told me that cannot convert a SimpleJdbcTemplate to a JdbcTemplate instance. I think bc I am inheriting the method setJbcdTemplate that receives a JdbcTemplate and not a SimpleJdbcTemplate. After figuring this out I thought I needed to tell the framework to injects a JdbcTemplate: 
    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also call your datasource directly in your dao bean, don't need to do an another bean for jdbcTemplate. So your context file become something like this:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/name" />
<bean id="dao" class="com.mycompany.mavenproject3.Dao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

After you just have to extends JdbcDaoSupport spring class (in which contain the getter and setter of datasource) on your Dao class.